# Wordpress url rewriting to post permalink

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I'm creating wordpress blog, which have permaling structure: /postname.html
I have to make another rewrite rule to this post: /firstLetterOfTitle/postname.html
Both rules have to work, first as default permalink.

I added code to my theme functions.php:

`add_rewrite_rule('^([a-z])/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)\.html$', '$matches[2]', 'top');`

and unfortunately it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Edit:
As Babar said, it should be

`add_rewrite_rule('/([a-z])/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)\.html$', '/index.php?pagename=$matches[2]', 'top');`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
add_rewrite_rule('/([a-z])/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)\.html$', '/index.php?p=$matches[2]', 'top');
```

(Not tested)

And remember to flush WordPress rewrite rules Manually after adding this code. (By re-saving the Permalink settings.)

Update (Just for note)
it should be like this:

```
add_rewrite_rule('/([a-z])/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)\.html$', '/index.php?pagename=$matches[2]', 'top');
```

Comment: It doesn't work :-(
And I call `flush_rewrite_rules();` after adding rewrite rule.

Comment: Sorry it should be like this:
`add_rewrite_rule('/([a-z])/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)\.html$', '/index.php?pagename=$matches[2]', 'top');`
You may try this.